# How do I import a pre-existing Java project into Eclipse and get up and running?

Tags: java, eclipse

*Comment on Duplicate Reference: Why would this be marked duplicate when it was asked years prior to the question referenced as a duplicate?  I also believe the question, detail, and response is much better than the referenced question.*

I've been a C++ programmer for quite a while but I'm new to Java and new to Eclipse.  I want to use the [touch graph "Graph Layout" code](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=30469&package_id=23976) to visualize some data I'm working with.

This code is organized like this:

```
./com
./com/touchgraph
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/Edge.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/GLPanel.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/graphelements
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/graphelements/GESUtils.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/graphelements/GraphEltSet.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/graphelements/ImmutableGraphEltSet.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/graphelements/Locality.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/graphelements/TGForEachEdge.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/graphelements/TGForEachNode.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/graphelements/TGForEachNodePair.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/graphelements/TGNodeQueue.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/graphelements/VisibleLocality.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/GraphLayoutApplet.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/GraphListener.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/DragAddUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/DragMultiselectUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/DragNodeUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/GLEditUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/GLNavigateUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/HVRotateDragUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/HVScroll.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/HyperScroll.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/LocalityScroll.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/RotateScroll.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/TGAbstractClickUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/TGAbstractDragUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/TGAbstractMouseMotionUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/TGAbstractMousePausedUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/TGSelfDeactivatingUI.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/TGUIManager.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/TGUserInterface.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/interaction/ZoomScroll.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/LocalityUtils.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/Node.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/TGAbstractLens.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/TGException.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/TGLayout.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/TGLensSet.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/TGPaintListener.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/TGPanel.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/TGPoint2D.java
./com/touchgraph/graphlayout/TGScrollPane.java
./TG-APACHE-LICENSE.txt
./TGGL ReleaseNotes.txt
./TGGraphLayout.html
./TGGraphLayout.jar
```

How do I add this project in Eclipse and get it compiling and running quickly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Create a new Java project in Eclipse.  This will create a src folder (to contain your source files).
2. Also create a lib folder (the name isn't that important, but it follows standard conventions).
3. Copy the `./com/*` folders into the `/src` folder (you can just do this using the OS, no need to do any fancy importing or anything from the Eclipse GUI).
4. Copy any dependencies (`jar` files that your project itself depends on) into `/lib` (note that this **should NOT** include the `TGGL jar` - *thanks to commenter Mike Deck for pointing out my misinterpretation of the OPs post!*)
5. Copy the other TGGL stuff into the root project folder (or some other folder dedicated to licenses that you need to distribute in your final app)
6. Back in Eclipse, select the project you created in step 1, then hit the F5 key (this refreshes Eclipse's view of the folder tree with the actual contents.
7. The content of the `/src` folder will get compiled automatically (with class files placed in the /bin file that Eclipse generated for you when you created the project).  **If you have dependencies** (which you don't in your current project, but I'll include this here for completeness), **the compile will fail initially because you are missing the dependency `jar files` from the project classpath.**
8. Finally, open the `/lib` folder in Eclipse, `right click` on each required `jar file` and choose `Build Path->Add` to build path.

That will add that particular jar to the classpath for the project.  Eclipse will detect the change and automatically compile the classes that failed earlier, and you should now have an Eclipse project with your app in it.

Comment: the TGGraphLayout.jar archive here isn't a dependency is just the compiled binary of the source that has been downloaded, therefore it doesn't need to be put into a lib directory and included on the build classpath.  In fact this could cause some very confusing behaviors in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem (similar).  I'd like to add that if you get the error "Failed to load main setting" (or something similar). Be sure that the /src/ folder is THE source folder for that project.  You can right click /src/ and select -> Use as Source Folder

Answer (score 13):

I think you'll have to import the project via the file->import wizard:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/419556/vc/Open-existing-project-Eclipse

It's not the last step, but it will start you on your way.

I also feel your pain - there is really no excuse for making it so difficult to do a simple thing like opening an existing project.  I truly hope that the Eclipse designers focus on making the IDE simpler to use (tho I applaud their efforts at trying different approaches - but please, Eclipse designers, if you are listening, never complicate something simple).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the difference is, but I have imported two different projects in two different ways - one may work for you: a) use the File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace and b) File->Import->General->File System.  Maybe one or the other may work for you.

Answer (score 11):

This assumes Eclipse and an appropriate JDK are installed on your system

1. Open Eclipse and create a new Workspace by specifying an empty directory.
2. Make sure you're in the Java perspective by selecting Window -> Open Perspective ..., select Other... and then Java
3. Right click anywhere in the Package Explorer pane and select New -> Java Project
4. In the dialog that opens give the project a name and then click the option that says "Crate project from existing sources."
5. In the text box below the option you selected in Step 4 point to the root directory where you checked out the project.  This should be the directory that contains "com"
6. Click Finish.  For this particular project you don't need to do any additional setup for your classpath since it only depends on classes that are part of the Java SE API.

Answer (score 6):

In the menu go to :
- File
- Import
- as the filter select 'Existing Projects into Workspace'
- click next
- browse to the project directory at 'select root directory'
- click on 'finish'