# Import java project into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I just downloaded a Google App Engine sample Java project.  I am trying to import it into eclipse.  If I chose file/import/existing projects into workspace, and navigate to the appropriate directory, it doesn't find any projects.  I'm speculating this means that dotmatrix is not an Eclipse project.  How can I import it?

Thanks.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142863/how-do-i-import-a-pre-existing-java-project-into-eclipse-and-get-up-and-running).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I import a pre-existing Java project into Eclipse and get up and running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142863/how-do-i-import-a-pre-existing-java-project-into-eclipse-and-get-up-and-running)

Answer (score 2):

Project you are trying to import doesn't seem like Eclipse Project.
You can still use this project in Eclipse as Java project by following these steps:

- Open Java Perspective in Eclipse.
- Right Click in Package explorer pane and select New >> Java Project.
- Give appropriate name to your Project and  click the option that says "Create project from existing sources."
- Select root dir of project downloaded and click finish.

Note: You may need to configure source folders, library and other build paths to complete setup.