# Java makefile to eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, makefile

I have an makefile version of a java project which is organized as follows:

```
CLASSFILES=Main/Main.class Lex/BooleanLiteral.class< and so on>
JAVAFILES=IR/*.java
CFILES=Runtime/*.c
```

I am looking to move this to Eclipse so that I would be able to debug it better( I need to implement a feature in this codebase and i need to understand the codeflow better. )

I am a C++ programmer and I have just moved to Java programming, i have tried to follow the instructions in this link 
[How do I import a pre-existing Java project into Eclipse and get up and running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142863/how-do-i-import-a-pre-existing-java-project-into-eclipse-and-get-up-and-running)
but i am getting the following error, the project was not built since its build path is not complete.  I am really stuck here, any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Subramanian

Comment: In the project settings you can set source paths and define required libraries; I'd look for some basic Eclipse tutorials to get started, although you may have an unusual directory structure to deal with.